# Map instead of for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, map-function

I have a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(k_poss)):
    k_poss[i][0] = ' '.join(k_poss[i][0])
```

Is it possible to use the map function for this instead? I know it could be something like

```
map(lambda x: ' '.join(x), k_poss)
```

but how would I go to the index I want in a map?

Comment: It's unlikely you will be able to rewrite these clear two lines with a single line and keep it readable. So why bother?

Comment: It's helpful to know what the list looks like

Comment: Are there non-zero columns in `k_poss` that need to be preserved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop over k_poss,
looping over a range of len of a object is considered non-Pythonic

```
for k in k_poss:
     k[0] = ' '.join(k[0])
```

which will make things more readable.

Since you asked, map will also work, but is really **not recommended**.

See @Jab's example

```
k_poss = list(map(lambda x: [' '.join(x[0])] + x[1:], iter(k_poss)))
```

from taken the comment section if you really want to use map, it's better than the attempts I had in here...

Comment: You're joining all of `x` in your map not `x[0]`

Comment: And returning a string instead of a list too

Comment: depending on k_poss, maybe it's safer to change that to iter(k_poss)

Comment: Doesn't this also lose all the non-zero columns of `k_poss`?

Comment: the for look doesn't lose all non zero bits, the map may.. Hmm, I'd never use map for stuff like this because it's so unreadable. I'll change the map part

Comment: The map is not correct still, you'd be losing data in each `x` this way. Don't use map for this. Just use the loop. If you want a one liner then make it a one liner. But that's just me

Comment: There's no reason to recreate the entire list from scratch just to update one small part of it. Python doesn't have the kind of optimizations that allow functional languages to do this efficiently. Stick with the `for` loop.

Comment: And to make the map even work you're doing yet another loop as a comprehension. This is just inefficient. Also you're missing a closing parentheses it should be `k_poss = list(map(lambda x: [' '.join(x[0])] + x[1:], iter(k_poss)))` if you use the map. And at that point I say it's too much work and readibility and efficiency is lost at that point.

Comment: @Jab, yes, I should just write, don't use map for this... Too late here to get it right without setting up a test example, I'll just mention your example instead.

Comment: I gave you a +1 as you did answer OP's question but to be honest I wouldn't answer with something that may work but is not the most optimal solution. I say guide them in the correct path and let them decide.

Comment: Add in the one liner in my answer so I can delete my answer as you do deserve the credit.

Comment: @Jab - Thanks & Done.